# Refer to "[Section], [Paragraph]" when [Paragraph] is custom formatted

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to have sections and single number paragraphs, like

```
2.3.1 Frobnication
    §1 Foo bar frob
```

which I achieved. But when when I refer to the paragraph ...

```
\myref{Paragraph's Label}
```

... but all I could achieve looks like:

```
See §1 (p. 1).
```

But I would like to have it like so:

```
See Section 2.3.1, §1 (p.1)
```

At the moment, this is my ref-command and my renewed `\theparagraph`:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{§\arabic{paragraph}}
\newcommand{\pararef}[1]{\ref{#1} (p. \pageref{#1})}
```

My current workaround is to have two parameters to `\pararef`, but it feels unclean and clumsy.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I can refine the section-command to define some user-command to be used within my custom ref-macro.

Comment: What about the package `scrjura` which offers such references?

Comment: @KeksDose: I've tried it; I think it is too intrusive for my purposes. However, I will at some point write a language-standard for a tiny programming language I've written (which is part of a bigger program (http://picogen.org)), and I think there it has a good place :)

Answer (score 6):

You can define a "reference prefix": if `foo` is a counter, then its value when a label refers to it is printed as

```
\p@foo\thefoo
```

where `\p@foo` is by default empty. So

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\S~\arabic{paragraph}}
\newcommand{\pararef}[1]{\ref{#1} (p.~\pageref{#1})}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@paragraph}{\thesubsubsection, }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{B}
\subsubsection{C}
\paragraph{D}\label{x}

This is the reference: \pararef{x}
\end{document}
```

If you don't always use `\paragraph` subordinate to subsubsections, then you can say

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@paragraph}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}=\z@
    \thesection
  \else
    \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=\z@
      \thesubsection
    \else
      \thesubsubsection
    \fi
  \fi,\space
}
\makeatother
```

This assumes that `\paragraph` is at least subordinate to a section. This is a test document

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\S~\arabic{paragraph}}
\newcommand{\pararef}[1]{\ref{#1} (p. \pageref{#1})}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@paragraph}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}=\z@
    \thesection
  \else
    \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=\z@
      \thesubsection
    \else
      \thesubsubsection
    \fi
  \fi,\space
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{B}
\subsubsection{C}
\paragraph{D}\label{x}

This is the reference: \pararef{x}

\section{E}
\paragraph{F}\label{y}

This is the reference: \pararef{y}

\section{G}
\subsection{H}
\paragraph{I}\label{z}

This is the reference: \pararef{z}
\end{document}
```

I've always found this kind of cross references heavy and not friendly to the reader.

Comment: +1, thanks. I like it for its minimalism; do you have more information on this prefix-thingy? And, can this also be made flexible enough when a paragraph is a descendant of section/subsection? So as to print `3 § 1 (p.1)` (instead of `3.0.1 § 1 (p.1)`)

Comment: @phresnel I've added the code as requested. However, I would *never* recommend such a style.

Comment: I see. I think then it would be better to define my own paragraph-command. Note that this is for technical documentation purposes where I will need some cross-references. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'll leave my original answer below so the comments make sense but a better solution is to use the built in prefixing mechanism for cross references (that by default isn't used for sections but is for nested lists). The command `\p@paragraph` is used at the start of any cross reference text (but mot when the counter is directly printed in the heading)

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\P\arabic{paragraph}}
\newcommand{\pararef}[1]{\ref{#1} (p. \pageref{#1})}

\def\p@paragraph{Section \@currentlabel\ }

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\section{jhg}
\paragraph{jj}\label{jj}
\subsection{ljhg}
\subsubsection{lkb ljhg}
\paragraph{jjj}\label{foo}

jhgg

\section{ojh}
 See \pararef{foo} and \pararef{jj}

\end{document}
```

Original answer:

One way is to put the long form into `\theparagraph` but not print it all when making the heading:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\protect\myswitch{Section \thesubsubsection\ }\P\arabic{paragraph}}
\newcommand{\pararef}[1]{\ref{#1} (p. \pageref{#1})}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\let\myswitch\@gobble\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}


\def\myswitch#1{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\section{jhg}
\subsection{ljhg}
\subsubsection{lkb ljhg}
\paragraph{jjj}\label{foo}

jhgg

\section{ojh}
 See \pararef{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, thanks. Can this also be made flexible enough when a paragraph is a descendant of section/subsection? So as to print `3 § 1 (p.1)` (instead of `3.0.1 § 1 (p.1)`)

Comment: well possibly but LaTeX's sectioning model really assumes that each sectioning command comes at a fixed level, \paragraph is _supposed_ to be used as a sus-sub-sub-section not as a unit that may appear at any level. Basically just replace `\thesubsubsection` by `\@currentlabel` in the definition of `\theparagraph` (move the definition after `\makeatletter` ) and it will pick up whatever is around....

Comment: What about a `\paragraph` following another `\paragraph`, with the new code? The reference will be wrong, because the first `\paragraph` sets `\@currentlabel`.

Comment: @egreg good point, that's the use of `\@currentlabel` rather than `\thesubsubsection` yes as I said in my 1st comment, latex's sectioning doesn't really support using the same sectioning command at different levels. Should either use `\thesubsubsection` or make sure each paragraph is in its own group so that `\@currentlabel` picks up the parent not the preceding paragraph. Either way I think using `\p@paragraph` is better than my first suggestion.